# Add values outside of an array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, statistics

I want to add the values from an array after subtracting another constant value and then squaring each value. I have tried the reduce method on the values, but I get an error. Here is the for loop I need to use:

```
 var dataset_1 = [1, 2, 3];
 var count_1 = dataset_1.length;
 var sum_1 = dataset_1.reduce(function(a,b){
 return a + b;
 }, 0  );
 var mean_1 = sum_1 / count_1;

 for(i = 0; i < count_1; i++){

  var stat_sq = Math.pow(dataset_1[i] - mean_1, 2);


  }
```

I need to add the values from the result of stat_sq, but the reduce method gives me this error, 
TypeError: stat_sq.reduce is not a function.
 I think I need to somehow get the values back into an array, but I don't know how.

Comment: And what's the error that you receive? With this code I know what is the error but you should learn to understand errors and to write good questions, as stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specially the **Pretend you're talking to a busy colleague** part.

Answer (score 0):

In line 2 dataset variable is not defined. You call it dataset_1.

Comment: Thank you for this advice. I have edited my post to include the definition to reflect count = dataset_1.length